# Unity- Standalone build run out of memory

Tags: memory, optimization, unity-game-engine, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

So I already asked this question on the unity forums but that didn't help me a lot :/. Today I decided to give my game a try with friends so basically I created a server so other clients/friends could connect to it. After about 20 minutes of playing my game crashed and I quickly checked task manager and my game was using about 3.5 GB of RAM! [PHOTO HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F0KM.png) When I looked at the log it said something like this:

```
Unity Player [version: Unity 4.6.1f1_d1db7a1b5196]

mono.dll caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)
  in module mono.dll at 0023:101071a1.

Error occurred at 2016-07-04_163050.
C:\Users\Cooler Master\Desktop\TL\TL.exe, run by Cooler Master.
77% memory in use.
0 MB physical memory [1814 MB free].
0 MB paging file [1039 MB free].
0 MB user address space [68 MB free].
Write to location 00000000 caused an access violation.
```

So in my game there is something that keeps eating my RAM. It takes about 3MB per second of ram when the game is running. I found some information on internet about Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets but I don't know how to write a script like that! I knew how to write in c# but only the easy scripts like GUI,Newtorkinf,Physics etc.. Also I downloaded unity pro from kickasstorrent only to see profiler window but that didn't help me at all

Thank very much for any reply !
Also if you want to check out the game and see what's happening : http://gamejolt.com/games/thuglifealpha/61660

Thanks again! :)

Comment: This problem will be hard to solve because it looks like the only to figure out what's going on is for us to see the source code.  Look for arrays in your code. something like `myclass = new Myclass[10];` in an update loop. do that once in the `Start` function then re-use it. Are you doing `myclass  = new Myclass()` from many scripts? Are you instantiating GameObjects with scripts attached to them? If so,stop and learn about object pooling. Looping over `List` with `foreach` loop? use `for` loops instead. There are many other possible problems. Without code, it's hard to help.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by: myclass = new Myclass Sorry for being dumb. But i'm only using unity for a  year so i'm still beginner. But i found that some people using method (already mentioned) Unloading Textures and assets but i can't find any script to that and i don't know how to write these kind of scripts do you know something about this? And also i have one script what is about 3500 lines long i tried to delete that script and build up the game but RAM is still going up. I changed size of all textures from 1024 to 256px but still no result. Older version of game is working fine.

Comment: Unity 5 free version comes pretty much with all the features as pro, so you can use profiler for free. Add some screenshots of profiler memory tab (click that take memory snapshot too)

Comment: @MatúšPavkeje every time you create an object, memory is allocated to hold that object.  Programmer, mgear and Denis Efimov are suggesting you go through your code and review where you are allocating memory as a start to the optimisation process.  This and other tactics are discussed in the manual as a good place to start: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileOptimizationPracticalScriptingOptimizations.html

Don't worry about UnloadingUnusedAssets or unloading specific textures until you know for sure that they are the problem. http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: Thanks to you all for suggestions! I will try my best to fix that ! Maybe it takes so much time because i have about 100 scripts in project

Comment: Problem solved! I disabled every single object in the scene an then i enabled one object build game check ram was ok a did it this way and the problem was causing my MiningSystem on stones in the update function i was sending by rpc  too many thing like floats,int,time,destroy time... So i have to rewrite that script and woala problem gone ! Thanks everybody again for suggestions ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code it is difficult to find exact issues. But I you should start from finding code where new objects are instantiated/destroyed. It causes GC to collect unused objects and allocate new memory. And soon your free memory becomes so fragmented that there is no suitable memory area to allocate new object.

I strongly recommend to read articles about optimization for Unity